# Vertical scroll recycler view with vertical scroll bars that show letter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to build the image below with the following requirements :

1. vertical scroll
2. vertical scroll using the vertical scroll bar that allows, filter scrolling, whilst showing the header title on scroll

At the present moment what I have is the following

I have a Recyclerview with the different view holders, one for the heading and the other for the country name

That shows the list of countries and their header. I am now trying to get the vertical scroll bar and use it to scroll for the desired effect below. If you are scrolling through your contact list on any phone this feature is there where the letters of the alphabet appear as you scroll up and down.

What would be the best and efficient method of going about implementing this ?

[image]